# Shared Preferences Issue? Android Java

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, gettext, settext

Hi i have used shared preferences to store a string in 'verified'. On the main activity i just need to be able to get the string and it will be used in an if statement. 
on the verified activity i must be able to enter a value into an editText and it will store it permenantly ( even when app is closed) until the app is deleted.
Here is my code it currently doesnt save the permenant string. I think it maybe something to do with the OnClickListner? But im not sure.

***MainActivity***

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {



    public static final String Verified = "";




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(Verified, 0);
String value = settings.getString("key","");


    if (MobileVerified.equals("")){
```

...

***Verified Class***

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

     {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.verified);

        Button VerifyCompleteButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.VerifyCompleteButton);

        VerifyCompleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

        {
           public void onClick(View view) 
           {    

             String NumberString;
             String Verified;

             Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

             NumberString = bundle.getString("NumberString");
             Verified = bundle.getString("Verified");



             //set String Verified permenantly

            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(Verified, 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putString("key", NumberString);
            editor.commit();


           } 



           });


 }
```

Comment: future note: please start your variables with small letters! Big ones should be used for classes. I was confused when I first took a look!

Comment: What is `Verified` in the context of the Verified class? That is, is `getSharedPreferences(Verified...` accessing a shared preferences file with the same name?

Comment: verified is just a variable used to store the string permenantly. It is used on the MainActivity to Get the string and its also used on the verified.class in order to add the string

Answer (score 0):

For a crash you should provide the stacktrace, but at least this is an obvious one:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(Verified, 0);
```

You're using the `Activity` as a `Context` too early, in member variable initialization phase. Move the `getSharedPreferences()` and the following `getValue()` calls to `onCreate()`.

After that, make sure you're passing the same preferences file name to `getSharedPreferences()` in both places. `getSharedPreferences(Verified, ...)` does not seem to be what you need, use something like `getSharedPreferences("verified", ...)` instead.

Comment: HI thanks, could you please advise me on the question as i have edited

Comment: I am using the same name for getSharedPreferences however it doesnt seem to be storing anything into the string?!

Answer (score 0):

Initialize `SharedPreferences` object inside the `onCreate()` instead before `onCreate()` method as below...

```
SharedPreferences settings;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
   String value = settings.getString("key","");
}
```

Comment: HI thanks, could you please advise me on the question as i have eddited